# IOS Programmatic tap using Earlgrey in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to use EarlGrey to programmatically tap the device view on objective c?
I tried doing that using this API with a tap recogniser:

```
CGPoint point;
point.x =2;
point.y=2;
[GREYActions actionForTapAtPoint:point];
```

It failed to get the tap event